# Why twitter stream api sends unnecessary data?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

As per twitter documentation

```
A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose Tweets should be delivered on the stream. Following protected users is not supported. For each user specified, the stream will contain:

Tweets created by the user.
Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).
```

Imagine I am following person X, he/she has millions of follower and whenever he/she tweets something a lot of followers retweet that, as per documentation streaming api will stream all that noise if I am following that id via twitter api. So my question is, is it just bad design or any specific for reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a design choice.

You're looking at a specific method of filtering Tweets (using the `follow` parameter). If what you want is *just* the Tweets posted by that user, you could use a different pattern like the `from:` operator.